# How can I perform Group Lasso?

Tags: linear-model, lasso, regularization

Suppose I have an $n \times p$ matrix of data, $X$, and a $p \times p$ matrix of coefficients $\beta$.  I'm interested in the folllowing:

$$ \min_{B} \Bigg\{ \lVert XB  - X \lVert_2^2 + \lambda \sum_{j = 1}^p \lVert B_{\cdot , j} \rVert_2 \Bigg\}$$

A couple of thoughts here:

- $B_{\cdot , j}$ is the $j^{th}$ row of $B$
- The norm I am using for the matrices is the Frobenius Norm, and the norm for the rows of $B$ is the  L2 norm.  Note that this is not the norm squared.

Here is my rational:

I want to retain a small number of columns of X such that we can use those to reconstruct the full matrix X with the least amount of error. One way of making that concrete is to say let’s reconstruct X using linear model(s) and minimize the squared Frobenius norm of the result.

A linear mapping from X to X is simply XB with the error being the frobenious norm of XB-X.

So, notice that if we eliminate a whole row of B, then we don’t need that column of X anymore to compute the product X*B.

I'm looking for a software implementation, either python or R it doesnt matter. Does this look familiar to anyone?  I've heard it is similar to Group Lasso.